# Symfony 2.6, pull in other bundle repository, container aware to fixtures

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.6

I am trying to pull in data from another bundles entity repository in a data fixtures file, to do this i am trying to implement container aware but its not working, is there any way i can run a query on another bundles entity repository from inside a data fixtures file ?

#### Comment Fixtures

```
namespace DomNoble\BlogBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use DomNoble\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog\Comments;
use DomNoble\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog\Posts;
use DomNoble\UserBundle\Entity\Users;

class CommentFixtures extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{

    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager('default')->getRepository('DomNobleUserBundle:Users');

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $em->loadUserByUsername('superadmin');
        $comment->setUserID($user->getId());
        $comment->setContent('To make a long story short. You can\'t go wrong by choosing Symfony! And no one has ever been fired for using Symfony.');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-1')));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $em->loadUserByUsername('bradpit');
        $comment->setUserID($user->getId());
        $comment->setContent('To make a long story short. Choosing a framework must not be taken lightly; it is a long-term commitment. Make sure that you make the right selection!');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-1')));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $em->loadUserByUsername('thejoker');
        $comment->setUserID($user->getId());
        $comment->setContent('Anything else, mom? You want me to mow the lawn? Oops! I forgot, New York, No grass.');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $em->loadUserByUsername('trollhat');
        $comment->setUserID($user->getId());
        $comment->setContent('Are you challenging me? ');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2011-07-23 06:15:20"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $em->loadUserByUsername('thejoker');
        $comment->setUserID($user->getId());
        $comment->setContent('Name your stakes.');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2011-07-23 06:18:35"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $em->loadUserByUsername('trollhat');
        $comment->setUserID($user->getId());
        $comment->setContent('If I win, you become my slave.');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2011-07-23 06:22:53"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $em->loadUserByUsername('thejoker');
        $comment->setUserID($user->getId());
        $comment->setContent('Your SLAVE?');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2014-07-23 06:25:15"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $em->loadUserByUsername('trollhat');
        $comment->setUserID($user->getId());
        $comment->setContent('You wish! You\'ll do shitwork, scan, crack copyrights...');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2014-07-23 06:46:08"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $em->loadUserByUsername('thejoker');
        $comment->setUserID($user->getId());
        $comment->setContent('And if I win?');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2014-07-23 10:22:46"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $em = $this->container()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        $user = $em->loadUserByUsername('trollhat');

        $comment->setUserID($user->getId());
        $comment->setContent('Make it my first-born!');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2014-07-23 11:08:08"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $em->loadUserByUsername('thejoker');
        $comment->setUserID($user->getId());
        $comment->setContent('Make it our first-date!');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2014-07-24 18:56:01"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $em->loadUserByUsername('trollhat');
        $comment->setUserID($user->getId());
        $comment->setContent('I don\'t DO dates. But I don\'t lose either, so you\'re on!');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2011-07-25 22:28:42"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $em->loadUserByUsername('doggg');
        $comment->setUserID($user->getId());
        $comment->setContent('It\'s not gonna end like this.');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-3')));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $em->loadUserByUsername('voltman');
        $comment->setUserID($user->getId());
        $comment->setContent('Oh, come on, Stan. Not everything ends the way you think it should. Besides, audiences love happy endings.');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-3')));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $em->loadUserByUsername('oldboy');
        $comment->setUserID($user->getId());
        $comment->setContent('Doesn\'t Bill Gates have something like that?');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-5')));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $em->loadUserByUsername('mylittlepony');
        $comment->setUserID($user->getId());
        $comment->setContent('Bill Who?');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-5')));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

When i try to run the fixtures command i get an error :

#### command

`doctrine:fixtures:load`

#### error

`Attempted to call method "container" on class "DomNoble\BlogBundle\DataFixt
  ures\ORM\CommentFixtures".`

what am i doing wrong here ? all i want to do is swap the user id from the username using the users repository. how can i accomplish this ?

#### Comments Entity

```
namespace DomNoble\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DomNoble\BlogBundle\Entity\Repository\CommentsRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="comments")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Comments
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DomNoble\UserBundle\Entity\Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $userID;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $approved;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Posts", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $post;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="img", type="array")
     */
    private $img;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCreated(new \DateTime());
        $this->setUpdated(new \DateTime());

        $this->setApproved(true);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function setUpdatedValue()
    {
       $this->setUpdated(new \DateTime());
    }


    public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('content', new NotBlank(array(
            'message' => 'You must enter a comment'
        )));
    }   


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set userID
     *
     * @param string $userID
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setUserID($userID)
    {
        $this->userID = $userID;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userID
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserID()
    {
        return $this->userID;
    }

    /**
     * Set post
     *
     * @param string $post
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setPost($post)
    {
        $this->post = $post;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get post
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPost()
    {
        return $this->post;
    }

    /**
     * Set approved
     *
     * @param integer $approved
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setApproved($approved)
    {
        $this->approved = $approved;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get approved
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getApproved()
    {
        return $this->approved;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set img
     *
     * @param array $img
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setImg($img)
    {
        $this->img = $img;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get img
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getImg()
    {
        return $this->img;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updated
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }


}
```

## Update:Solved!

there were a few problems with the above code one mistake jack mentioned also `getEntityManager` became `getManager` and i was trying to supply the id rather than the user object to  the comment entity. here it is now working :

#### Comment Fixtures

```
namespace DomNoble\BlogBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use DomNoble\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog\Comments;
use DomNoble\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog\Posts;
use DomNoble\UserBundle\Entity\Users;

class CommentFixtures extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{

    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $userRepo = $em->getRepository('DomNobleUserBundle:Users');

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $userRepo->loadUserByUsername('superadmin');
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setContent('To make a long story short. You can\'t go wrong by choosing Symfony! And no one has ever been fired for using Symfony.');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-1')));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $userRepo->loadUserByUsername('bradpit');
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setContent('To make a long story short. Choosing a framework must not be taken lightly; it is a long-term commitment. Make sure that you make the right selection!');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-1')));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $userRepo->loadUserByUsername('thejoker');
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setContent('Anything else, mom? You want me to mow the lawn? Oops! I forgot, New York, No grass.');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $userRepo->loadUserByUsername('trollhat');
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setContent('Are you challenging me? ');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2011-07-23 06:15:20"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $userRepo->loadUserByUsername('thejoker');
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setContent('Name your stakes.');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2011-07-23 06:18:35"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $userRepo->loadUserByUsername('trollhat');
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setContent('If I win, you become my slave.');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2011-07-23 06:22:53"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $userRepo->loadUserByUsername('thejoker');
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setContent('Your SLAVE?');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2014-07-23 06:25:15"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $userRepo->loadUserByUsername('trollhat');
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setContent('You wish! You\'ll do shitwork, scan, crack copyrights...');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2014-07-23 06:46:08"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $userRepo->loadUserByUsername('thejoker');
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setContent('And if I win?');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2014-07-23 10:22:46"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $userRepo->loadUserByUsername('trollhat');
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setContent('Make it my first-born!');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2014-07-23 11:08:08"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $userRepo->loadUserByUsername('thejoker');
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setContent('Make it our first-date!');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2014-07-24 18:56:01"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $userRepo->loadUserByUsername('trollhat');
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setContent('I don\'t DO dates. But I don\'t lose either, so you\'re on!');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-2')));
        $comment->setCreated(new \DateTime("2011-07-25 22:28:42"));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $userRepo->loadUserByUsername('doggg');
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setContent('It\'s not gonna end like this.');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-3')));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $userRepo->loadUserByUsername('voltman');
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setContent('Oh, come on, Stan. Not everything ends the way you think it should. Besides, audiences love happy endings.');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-3')));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $userRepo->loadUserByUsername('oldboy');
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setContent('Doesn\'t Bill Gates have something like that?');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-5')));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $user = $userRepo->loadUserByUsername('mylittlepony');
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setContent('Bill Who?');
        $comment->setPost($manager->merge($this->getReference('post-5')));
        $manager->persist($comment);

        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

#### Comment Entity

```
namespace DomNoble\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DomNoble\BlogBundle\Entity\Repository\CommentsRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="comments")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Comments
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DomNoble\UserBundle\Entity\Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $approved;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Posts", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $post;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="img", type="array")
     */
    private $img;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCreated(new \DateTime());
        $this->setUpdated(new \DateTime());

        $this->setApproved(true);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function setUpdatedValue()
    {
       $this->setUpdated(new \DateTime());
    }


    public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('content', new NotBlank(array(
            'message' => 'You must enter a comment'
        )));
    }   


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param string $userID
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set post
     *
     * @param string $post
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setPost($post)
    {
        $this->post = $post;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get post
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPost()
    {
        return $this->post;
    }

    /**
     * Set approved
     *
     * @param integer $approved
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setApproved($approved)
    {
        $this->approved = $approved;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get approved
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getApproved()
    {
        return $this->approved;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set img
     *
     * @param array $img
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setImg($img)
    {
        $this->img = $img;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get img
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getImg()
    {
        return $this->img;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updated
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }


}
```

another solution to this problem would have been to use the `OrderedFixtureInterface` and reference all the comments to users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the line

```
    $em = $this->container()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
```

with

```
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
```

Comment: the line i have is `$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager('default')->getRepository('DomNobleUserBundle:Users') ;` with no brackets on container

Comment: yea solved this one of the problems was the line you mention above i will post an update.